# Run rule on outllook when new email received

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created a rule that will move an email to the determined folder then run a script that checks for unread emails, marks as read and enters the deciphered email into a database. The problem I am having is that if all the mail in the specified folder is already read the email moves to the specified folder in the rule but the script doesn't run on the new email. But if I have one unread in the specified folder as soon as a new email comes in it marks the previous email as read and the script runs, but not on the new email, it still gets moved to the determined folder but doesn't have the script run on it. Is this because the script is running before it finishes moving to the specified folder.

Comment: Run the script before moving it, then move it

Comment: Outlook doesn't allow me to do this every time i check run rule first then check  move,  the move is applied before the run script

Comment: Well include the move in your script- have the rule just run the script- you know what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process items as they enter the Inbox before moving the item. Remove all code to search for items in the target folder. There should not be any unprocessed items there.

Where you use the "run a script" option in the Rules Wizard:

```
Sub runAScriptCode_ForARule(itm As MailItem)

    Dim InBoxFolder As Folder
    Dim targetFolder As Folder

    Set InBoxFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set targetFolder = InBoxFolder.Folders("MBAA LEADS")

    ' Put the code to process the incoming item here.
    ' There is no need to search for the item. It is "itm"
    ' Move the item after processing is done.

    MsgBox "itm.Subject: " & itm.Subject & vbCr & vbCr & _
      "Incoming item processed." & vbCr & vbCr & _
      "Click OK to move incoming item to " & targetFolder.Name

    itm.Move targetFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I didn't think to process it first then move it :( I guess I was over thinking it